# Bus error. Cannot access memory

Tags: c

I'm getting bus error.

While debugging the snippet below  and stepping to the end of writeDmpFile I'm getting:

```
writeDmpFile (tree=0x56a310, filename=0x7fffffffd450 "20140318.221058") at unzipper_m1.c:146
146 }
(gdb) n
Cannot access memory at address 0x38353031323236
```

The file is written though, but program ends with bus error.
Here the code:

```
typedef struct dmpParams_t
{
  char buff[6000000];
  size_t *size;
}dmpParams_t;

int writeFile(char *name,  unsigned char *buff, size_t *size,const char *dir )
{
  FILE * pFile;
  chdir (dir);
  pFile = fopen ( name, "wb");
  fwrite (buff , sizeof(unsigned char), *size, pFile);
  fclose (pFile);

  return 1;
}

int writeDmpFile(GTree *tree, char *filename)
{
  char dmpfilename[32];

  dmpfilename[0] ='\0';
  dmpParams_t params;
  params.buff[0]   ='\0';
  size_t size =0;
  params.size=&size ;
  g_tree_foreach(tree, (GTraverseFunc)writeDmpFileLine, &params);
  sprintf (dmpfilename, "InstrumentList_FULL.csv_%.*s", 15, filename);
  writeFile(dmpfilename,  ( unsigned char *)params.buff,  &size , dmpdir);//(size_t *)params.size, dmpdir);
}
```

Comment: This is not "all the code". How do these functions get called? The memory location that "cannot be accessed" is _clearly_ pointing to a location that is not in most memory maps - unless you have 16 million GB of RAM...

Comment: Yes, but the address must be overwritten in the presented part.

Comment: `char buff[6000000];` is around 6 MB, this is too much for the stack in a lot of systems. Use `malloc` to allocate this array... or use a smaller array.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a buffer overrun of `dmpfilename`. You allocated an array of length 32. You then format it with `"InstrumentList_FULL.csv_%.*s"`. That's 24 characters, plus 15 for the filename, plus a null terminator. That's more than 32.

Increase the size of the buffer.

Oh, and `dmpParams_t` is, er, rather large. Perhaps there's a stack overflow when you allocate one of those as a local.

Some other comments:

1. You could usefully use `const` a bit more.
2. Declaring `size` as `size_t*` in the struct is a bit odd. You pass the address of the struct to `g_tree_foreach`. I'd declare `size` as `size_t` and let `g_tree_foreach` modify the value.
3. Likewise, it seems odd that you pass the address of `size` to `writeFile`. Again a const value seems to make more sense.